# Почему на Safari слайдер листается медленно, на всех остальных браузерах хорошо?

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari, jpeg

Всем привет.
Такая ситуация:
Настраивал слайдер на сайт, брал от [сюда](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WeeF_lu0PIU) .
И столкнулся с тем, что он на всех браузерах работает хорошо при перелистывании, но вот на Safari - при каждом клике думает 3-4 секунды.
В галерее сейчас где-то 15 фоток по 900кб в среднем.Но дело в том что по специфике даного слайдера фотки должны быть максимально хорошего качества.И большого разрешения.
Грешил на скрипты, но тогда слайдер был бы криво работающий или еще чего, а здесь если фото уменьшить до качества хуже не придумаешь(по 100кб), тогда на Safari летает.

Почему так происходит с этим браузером?Перерыл кучу статей так и не разобрался.
Возможно что-то упускаю...

Если что вот ссылка на мой [слайдер](http://koftastudio.com/test/)

Comment: [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Comment: @Max Darkleviathan, зачем сразу загружать исходную картинку, когда можно сделать миниатюрку в 5-10 кб, а при необходимости показывать исходную?

Comment: http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ Попробуйте использовать вот этот слайдер. Его можно настроить на нужное вам поведенение.

Answer (score 2):

1. Понимаю, что скорее всего того требуют обстоятельства, но все же спрошу: почему именно этот слайдер? Ведь столько есть легких и удобных слайдеров, которые легко настраиваются, которым не нужны тяжелые картинки.
2. Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. 900 кб для мобильного браузера... Понимаю что "ретина", но попробуйте загнать свои картинки в любой онлайн оптимизатор. Да хоть тот же [оптимизатор картинок](http://compressor.io)

3.Все же что-то вы там намудрили. В хроме очень тяжело свайпать ваши картинки. Почти до конца надо мышкой отводить. В то время как на изначальном сайте(слайдера) все прекрасно.

Comment: 1.Здесь даже главная функция не свайп.
Важно само построение Cowerflow.Тоесть по центру картинка, по бокам превьюшки.И листать нажав на следующий\предыдущий слайд или прокручивая мышкой по кругу.И чтоб он был так же адаптивным.Я уже находил массу вариантов, но они все были не адаптивными.

2.Фотки уже ужаты оптимизатором.Там разрешение должно оставаться в пределах 4000px в ширину.

3.Если есть соображения или примеры подобного адаптивного слайдера ,буду благодарен за ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

Откройте гугл хром. зайдите на свой слайдер. нажмите ctrl-u и полюбуйтесь на свою кнопку закрыть.

Comment: Да, я видел.форматирование base64.
В любом случае, я его только что заменил на обычную иконку, но ситуация ровным счетом не меняется ни лучше ни хуже.